# Ionic 3 Native - LinkedIn login error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

I have used [ionic native linkedin](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/linkedin/) plugin in Ionic 3 app.

My code:

```
var scopes = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'rw_company_admin', 'w_share'];
this.linkedin.login(scopes, true).then((res) => {
    console.log(res) ;
}, (err) => {
    console.log(err) ;
});
```

And i have error:

> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'LinkedInLoginScopes[]'. Type 'string' is not assignable to type
>   'LinkedInLoginScopes'.

Help me please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define the type of `scopes`.

Type of `scopes` argument in plugin wrapper-

> export type LinkedInLoginScopes = 'r_basicprofile' | 'r_emailaddress'
>   | 'rw_company_admin' | 'w_share';
>
> login(scopes: LinkedInLoginScopes[], promptToInstall: boolean):
>   Promise { return; }

```
let scopes:any = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'rw_company_admin', 'w_share'];
```

or

```
 let scopes:Array<string> = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'rw_company_admin', 'w_share'];


    this.linkedin.login(scopes, true).then((res) => {
        console.log(res) ;
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err) ;
    });
```

Comment: The error is the same. Solved as `var scopes:any = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'rw_company_admin', 'w_share'];`

Comment: Great. Updated answer. Better to use let.

Comment: It'd be great if you could add some more details related to the cause of the error and why your solution fixes it. Otherwise, it may not help other SO users facing a similar issue

Comment: Ok, i will do that. @sebaferreras

Answer (score 0):

Define it as follows:

```
scopes: LinkedInLoginScopes[] = ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'rw_company_admin', 'w_share'];
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this would help the OP? As it stands right now, this answer is not helpful for others trying to understand the issue.